# How we can pass uid from angular firestore that we use in firestore security rules

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am talking about uid that we access like this in security rules
**request.auth.uid**

I know there is a method to make firestore login using email and password **signInWithEmailAndPassword**

I want to know how I pass uid that we access in security rules in request.auth
Thank You So Much In Advance

Comment: The uid is being set as soon as you use any authentication methods from Firebase via angularfire or the js-sdk, so at the security rules, you will always have this `request.auth.uid` available. Please take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw) to learn more about Firestore Security Rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Firebase Authentication, the UID (and the entire auth token) are automatically passed to the security rules of Firestore. They're available in `request.auth` in your rules, so for example: `request.auth.uid` for the UID of the user who made the request.

Outside of signing in with Firebase Authentication, there is no way for your code to influence the `auth.request.uid`. If there was, that'd be a huge security risk - as it'd allow malicious users to pass any UID they'd want and gain access to data they aren't authorized to.